# Inital calls from AngularJS form to controller? How to render page after all data is gathered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and I have a question about pre-setup my form.

The default URL of my page is, e.g., **localhost:3000/#/projectconfig.** I want the following to happen:  when page is loaded, a routine is called automatically from controller. It sets $scope.newproject=true in case of default URL or it calls server for some data to fill if URL contains a project ID after it, that is, looks like **localhost:3000/#/projectconfig/1** . So I need to call some routine and check the data from URL to it, how I precisely declare it in form and its controller?

When page is invoked, I need to get some data from server. And I do not want the page to render before the data are received. This concerns abovementioned case when projectId is specified and I need to pre-fill the form with its data.

Thank you in advance,
Askar

Comment: What have you tried? You should first look into [`ngRoute`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things, a **[router](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)**, and a `resolve` function.

**Quote from the official docs**

> An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the
>   controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will
>   wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the
>   controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved
>   successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and
>   $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are
>   rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired.

**A simple example:**

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/something/:param', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'MyCtrl',resolve: {
            myVar: function($q,$http){
                var deffered = $q.defer();

                    // make your http request here and resolve its promise

                return deffered.promise;
            }
        }}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

myVar will then be injected to your controller, containing the promise data.

**About the URL paramter**

Notice the parameter of the first route `/something/:param`

If you make a call to `localhost:3000/#/projectconfig/something/foobar`, you can access the parameter through the [**$route**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route#example) service:

`$route.current.params.param == 'foobar'`

**Injecting via service**

You could also avoid the additional DI parameter by returning a service you were going to inject anyways:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'MyCtrl',resolve: {
                myService: function($q,$http,myService){
                  var deffered = $q.defer();

                      /*  make your http request here
                      *   then, resolve the deffered's promise with your service.
                      */

                  deffered.resolve(myService),

                  return deffered.promise;
                }
            }}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

---

Have a look at [**egghead**](http://egghead.io), a great resource for learning Angular stuff